# Payment not completed in Apple Pay

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I do not have an actual device to test Apple Pay implementation, therefore, I am using emulator (iPhone 6), when I click Apple Pay button, and I could able to see all the information (PaymentRequest) that I have set it up manually.

However, when I click `Pay with Passcode` button, I am getting `tokenizedApplePayPayment = nil` and it shows payment not completed.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]]) {
      UIButton *button = [self applePayButton];
      [self.view addSubview:button];
  }
}

- (UIButton *)applePayButton {
    UIButton *button;

    if ([PKPaymentButton class]) { // Available in iOS 8.3+
        button = [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:PKPaymentButtonTypeBuy style:PKPaymentButtonStyleBlack];
    }

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedApplePay) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return button;
}

- (IBAction)tappedApplePay {
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [self paymentRequest];
    PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *vc = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:paymentRequest];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (PKPaymentRequest *)paymentRequest {
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.xxxx.xxxx";
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard];
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
    paymentRequest.countryCode = @"US"; // e.g. US
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = @"USD"; // e.g. USD
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems =
    @[
      [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Beef Kabob" amount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]],
      // Add add'l payment summary items...
      [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"XXX" amount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"110"]]
      ];
    return paymentRequest;
}

- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {

    // Example: Tokenize the Apple Pay payment
    BTApplePayClient *applePayClient = [[BTApplePayClient alloc]
                                        initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];
    [applePayClient tokenizeApplePayPayment:payment
                                 completion:^(BTApplePayCardNonce *tokenizedApplePayPayment,
                                              NSError *error) {
                                     if (tokenizedApplePayPayment) {
                                         completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess);
                                     } else {
                                         // Tokenization failed. Check `error` for the cause of the failure.

                                         // Indicate failure via the completion callback:
                                         completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
                                     }
                                 }];
}

- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not test Apple Pay with simulator. You have to use real device because for simulator Apple is sending token value as nil.